# Differences in Economic models

Tags: political-economy

Is '[Market Socialism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Market_socialism)' & '[Libertarian Socialism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libertarian_socialism)' functionally identical? What are the basic differences?

Comment: There is no clear definition for these concepts. If you care to provide the definitions you think are valid users may be able to point out key policy differences.

Comment: One of the key difference that I've figured out is that in Market Socialism the presence of Police is inevitable but in the case of Libertarian Socialism there is no requirement of Police in such societies.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not provide a definition. Without a proper definition you are likely to get answers like Mustang's.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Market_socialism                                                        https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libertarian_socialism

Comment: These definitions are still not narrow enough. Quoting from the first one: "Depending on the specific model of market socialism" so there are several models, which one do you mean? Quoting from the second one: "Libertarian socialism [...] is a group of anti-authoritarian political philosophies" so there are more versions of this too and these all seem to be ethical philosphies, not practical economic models?

Comment: It is true that these are ethical models and that's why I am asking for the difference between the basic ideas in between these two ideologies. It is difficult to be specific here because it will take time to write down everything. But thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Mustang You're not complying with the guidelines of the community. http://economics.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice **Be nice.**